# Passing an if statement as a function argument in R

Tags: r, function, null, arguments

I am writing a function with multiple functions inside of it (a wrapper to train and test multiple models with the caret package).

The issue is, sometimes I would like to use the default arguments and sometimes I would like to specify my own. In my case, sometimes I want to modify tuneGrid and sometimes I want to use the default grid. I cannot use ellipses (...) to pass down this argument for this because each model needs a separate grid.

How can I include an if statement in a functions arguments for this? For example,

```
family = NULL
y <- rnorm(1000); x <- rnorm(1000)
glm(formula=y~x, if(!is.null(family)){family=family}, data=data.frame(x=x, y=y))
```

This doesn't work for a number of reasons, but I hope you get the idea. I am trying to use something like this instead as the second argument to account for the commas:

```
noquote( ifelse( !is.null(family), paste0(noquote("family="), family, "(),") ) )
```

Please let me know if you have any ideas.

Comment: Why couldn't you just leave it missing to the function, rather than being NULL? Missing arguments are passed on to other functions. Could you show the full function that contains the `family=NULL...` code?

Comment: It is quite long code so it may not be useful if I posted it. Basically, what I am trying to do is train a bunch of different models and then test them.

(Sorry I hit enter by accident)

    data(Boston)

    glmBoostGrid = data.frame(mstop = floor((1:10) * 50), 
                                   prune = "no")


    train(form= medv~.,
          data = Boston,
          method = "glmboost",
          tuneGrid = glmBoostGrid
          )

So for example sometimes I want to use the default grid and sometimes I don't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could build your function call as a quoted expression and dynamically change it. Something like

```
addGrid<-function(expr, grid=NULL) {
    if(!is.null(grid)) {
        ll<-as.list(expr)
        ll$tuneGrid <- grid
        as.call(ll)
    } else {
        expr
    }
}

mycall<-quote(train(form= medv~., data = Boston, method = "glmboost"))
addGrid(mycall)
# train(form = medv ~ ., data = Boston, method = "glmboost")
addGrid(mycall, quote(glmBoostGrid))
# train(form = medv ~ ., data = Boston, method = "glmboost", tuneGrid = glmBoostGrid)
```

This returns an expression that you would then call `eval()` on to execute.

Otherwise you could use an `if` with a partial statement to possibly fill further values.

```
mybase<-function(...) {
    train(form= medv~., data = Boston, method = "glmboost", ...)
}
result <- if (!is.null(family)) {
    mybase(family=family)
} else {
    mybase()
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is wonderful. Exactly what I was trying to do and I can see a lot of uses for it within my code. 

I want to vote you up, but I'm new to stackoverflow and haven't reached the 15 rep.

Comment: Honestly I don't know if i'm a huge fan of either of these strategies. Sometimes just a simple `if` statement is clearer. If=t all depends on how general the function *really* has to be

Comment: Is there a way to put the if statement in the argument directly? My initial example with glm didn't work but something like this works:

x <- 1:10000;
plot( if(mean(x)>100){x})

Comment: The whole point of this is to avoid the `if` in parameter. The problem is that if it's not true passes a NULL along. So i'm not sure it makes sense to say `x <- 1:20; plot( if(mean(x)>100){x})` "works", right? Don't put in an `if` unless there's an `else` that makes sense for the function. This `if` i was talking about was `if(TRUE) {a(x=10:15)} else {a(x=1:5)}`